# Why can't ifconfig see network card information In a customized Linux?

Tags: linux

I am customizing the Linux system. Why can't `ifconfig` see network card
`enp1s0` information? But can `ls/sys/class/net` see the network card? Do I have to configure an IP? Why can't `ifconfig` even see `lo`?

```
# ls /sys/class/net
enp1s0  enp2s0  lo
# ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:B4:60:C6:C2
          inet addr:192.168.5.2  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:b4ff:fe60:c6c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:107063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:207378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6752435 (6.4 MiB)  TX bytes:24490846 (23.3 MiB)
```

Comment: Do you see them with `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: FYI, `ifconfig` is deprecated and has been replaced by `ip`. Try `ip a` to check on your interfaces.

Comment: @eblock Nice.Using `ifconfig - a`, I can see that. Why only `ifconfig` is required for kernel 4.1.15, but now I need `ifconfig - a` for kernel 6.4.0?

Comment: @doneal24 Thank you for the reminder, but I am currently using `busybox-1.36.1` to create my root file system, so I am still using `ifconfig`.

Comment: If an interface is down, ifconfig without -a won't display it, as usual.

Comment: And busybox does support ip commands. But you might have to enable it if compiling it yourself.